# Should I use "and" or "or"?

Tags: word-choice

I ran a study where I found that as temperature increases by 1%, violence increases by 1%, holding cloud cover and precipitation constant. As cloud cover decreases by 1%, violence increases by 2%, holding precipitation and temperature constant. As precipitation decreases by 1%, violence increases by 5%, holding temperature and cloud cover constant.

What is the best way to summarize my results?

(1) Days with high temperature, low cloud cover, **and** low precipitation see more violence.

(2) Days with high temperature, low cloud cover, **or** low precipitation see more violence.

(3) Days with high temperature, low cloud cover, **and/or** low precipitation see more violence.

Comment: I wrote an answer, but realised I was confused by the 'all else constant'. It might be clearer to write (version 2) 'when the other two factors are held constant'. Or perhaps: 'high temperature, low cloud cover, and low precipitation all correlate with an increase in violence.'

Comment: Mostly, when we see *all else constant*, it refers to unmentioned things, not to items listed in a variational system such as yours.  I would avoid trying to summarize these in a list. There really isn't any good way to do this short of esoteric mathematical symbols and language.

Comment: Noted. I edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because all three variables -- temperature, cloud cover, and precipitation -- are independent factors as they correlate to violence, the correct conjunction is **or**.

If violence increased when there was both low cloud cover and low precipitation, for example, but not when only one of these was lowered, then *and* might be more appropriate.

But each of your three factors are not dependent on the others, so it's definitely an ***or*** situation.